# Strange behaviour in hierarchical menu?

Tags: php, menu, nested, hierarchical

The function is simple:

```
 function showMenu( $level = 0 ) {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `menus` WHERE `submenu`=".$level;

    $result = mysql_query( $sql );

    echo "<ul>";

        while ( $node = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) {

            echo "<li>". $node['name'];

            $sql_ = "SELECT * FROM `menus` WHERE `submenu`=".$node['id'];

            $hasChild = mysql_fetch_array( mysql_query( $sql_ ) ) != null;

            if ( $hasChild ) {

                showMenu( $node['id'] );

            }

            echo "</li>";

        }

    echo "</ul>";

 }
```

But the results when I'm using the level 1 or over is strange. For example:

```
showMenu( 1 );
```

will return me all the items, except first items.

Comment: omg. did you write that function?

Comment: no, it was on stackoverflow, but I dont remember where. I know it's out of time ( 'cause PDO etc. ), but just interesting.

Answer (score 2):

```
function showMenu( $level = 0 ) {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `menus` WHERE `submenu`=".$level;

    $result = mysql_query( $sql );

    echo "<ul>";
      $rows = "";
        while ( $node = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) {

            echo "<li>". $node['name'];

            $sql_ = "SELECT * FROM `menus` WHERE `submenu`=".$node['id'];

            $execute = mysql_query( $sql_ );

            $rows = mysql_num_rows($execute);
            if ( $rows>0 ) {

                showMenu( $node['id'] );

            }

            echo "</li>";

        }

    echo "</ul>";

 }
```

Comment: that very nice, but recursive function, multiple packets, i would not recommend that.

Comment: I'm still confused, the first elements with level = 0 is missing.

Comment: Just write down it  if($level==0){$sql = "SELECT * FROM `menus` WHERE `submenu`= '0'";}else{"SELECT * FROM `menus` WHERE `submenu`=".$level;}

Comment: can you post db structure ?

Answer (score 0):

First, i think great coders never copy and paste code. its meant to fail.

that why for my opinion you have to get all menus (including the submenus). its better that way, because that you sending only one packet to sql.

now that you have all menu in object. (hey, we are in year 2013: use `mysqli` object oriented) you can check every time in simple `if` statement weather to build new `<ul>` tag.

Hope it helps.